# how to copy paste table in MySQL to another place(hard drive)?

Tags: innodb

I am having trouble with the issue:
  Our server is down so I am dealing with a lot of data on my Local server. The thing is, I want to save the table as a file  accessible by others as well online, say on google drive. In other words, I want to have the table editable on google drive and someone else could just copy and paste it into their MySQL database.

However, the database type 'InnoDB' seems not able to deal with this issue easily(copy paste is not easily applicable). So would it be possible that someone tell me any method to make the table a portable file in hard drive? That way everyone could be able to check and edit it conveniently. But please don't tell me to put them into csv...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to export the schema to a `.sql` file. It essentially consists of all the code to create and setup the tables for your database and it will save all the data inside its tables respectively.

Since you're using MySQL, to export, use this in your Terminal:

```
$ mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] db_name > /path/to/destination/backup_of_db.sql
```

And then to import it back into MySQL, use this in your Terminal:

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h localhost db_name < /path/from/destination/backup_of_db.sql
```

Also, I would not advise sending your `.sql` files over the web unless you absolute have to. This is of course depends on how sensitive the data is to your company's or clients' data that is stored in it.